# How to detect what is the current self.view position

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, cgaffinetransform

I've made an app (game) where randomly the view rotates from `portrait` to `upsideDownPortrait` using a NSTimer.

All works fine using the code below. When this section of the game ends, I need to correct the view so it reverts back to portrait and not upsideDown portrait. How do I detect what the current position is? `(float rotation = 180;)`

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 180 * (rotation+=180));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to "detect the current state of the view" when dealing with transforms if all you want to do is revert back to the original positioning.

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Will "undo" all the changes to the view's matrix that you have set.

Comment: Because the view will randomly change from portrait to upsideDown many times - surly your answer will revert the view back to its last change and not the initial correct way up... I'll give it go and let you know.

Comment: I stand corrected Sir !  Well done - Ive just tried it and sure enough, it reverts back to its original position. Nice !!